# Hide toggle nav when modal is showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button on which there is submenu toggle, when clinking on the button its showing the submenu and when clicked on third item **"clear my checklist"** its launching the bootstrap modal, what I want is to hide the toggle menu when bootstrap modal is visible.

Here is the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/4dov2fwn/1/

```
 $("#guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-submit___widget").click(function(e){
    $(".btn-options").toggle();
});
$(".btn-options > ul > li > a:contains('Clear my checklist')").click(function(e){
    $("#clear_all_checklist").modal("show");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: `$(".btn-options").toggle();` before `$("#clear_all_checklist").modal("show");`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I have actually used your suggestion but noticing new thing, when I toggle and show modal, but when modal is closed and click again in button to toggle is not showing the submenu on first click, have to do the second click. how can that be handled?

Comment: `$(".btn-options").toggle();` won't have any effects to attached event, can you share your updated fiddle?

Comment: actually works fine

Comment: yeah you are welcome :p

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can just use hide to the menu using jquery hide();
https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/4dov2fwn/3/

```js
$("#guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-submit___widget").click(function(e){
        $(".btn-options").toggle();
});
$(".btn-options > ul > li > a:contains('Clear my checklist')").click(function(e){
        $("#clear_all_checklist").modal("show");
        $(".btn-options").hide();
        e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.button-medium{margin-top:200px}
.btn-options {
 position: absolute;
 left: 12px;
 top: 251px;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.btn-options > ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.btn-options > ul > li {
 list-style: none;
}
.btn-options > ul > li > a {
 display: block;
 padding: 8px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.btn-options > ul > li > a:hover {
 background: #f4f4f4;
 color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button class="btn  button-medium submit" type="button" id="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-submit___widget" name="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-submit___jqName" style="position: relative;" tabindex="0" aria-label="Options" placeholder="" aria-describedby="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-submit___guideFieldLongDescription" data-original-title="" title="">
               <i class="sg-Btn-icon "></i>
        <span class="iconButton-icon"></span> 
        <span class="iconButton-label" data-guide-button-label="true" style="">Options</span>

    </button>
<div class="btn-options" style="display: none;"><ul>
<li><a href="#" target="_self"> Print my checklist </a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self"> Email my checklist </a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self"> Clear my checklist </a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self"> Sign out of my checklist </a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- Model Here -->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="clear_all_checklist">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

As well as you can do that using addClass in jQuery like this

https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/4dov2fwn/2/

```js
$("#guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-submit___widget").click(function(e){
        $(".btn-options").toggle();
});
$(".btn-options > ul > li > a:contains('Clear my checklist')").click(function(e){
        $("#clear_all_checklist").modal("show");
        $(".btn-options").addClass('hide');
        e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.button-medium{margin-top:200px}
.btn-options {
 position: absolute;
 left: 12px;
 top: 251px;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.btn-options > ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.btn-options > ul > li {
 list-style: none;
}
.btn-options > ul > li > a {
 display: block;
 padding: 8px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.btn-options > ul > li > a:hover {
 background: #f4f4f4;
 color: #000;
}
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button class="btn  button-medium submit" type="button" id="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-submit___widget" name="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-submit___jqName" style="position: relative;" tabindex="0" aria-label="Options" placeholder="" aria-describedby="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-submit___guideFieldLongDescription" data-original-title="" title="">
               <i class="sg-Btn-icon "></i>
        <span class="iconButton-icon"></span> 
        <span class="iconButton-label" data-guide-button-label="true" style="">Options</span>

    </button>
<div class="btn-options" style="display: none;"><ul>
<li><a href="#" target="_self"> Print my checklist </a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self"> Email my checklist </a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self"> Clear my checklist </a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self"> Sign out of my checklist </a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- Model Here -->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="clear_all_checklist">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```